# How to convert a PointCloud via tf2

Tags: transforms, pcl, tf2, pointcloud, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,

I tried to write some pretty simple code with tf2 and I'm stuck already.

How does one transform a `pcl::PointCloud<...>` when using `tf2` (and, less importantly, how about transforming a `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2`)?
With `tf` there is the `pcl_ros` package which can transform pcl-PointClouds with `tf::Transform`.
There's also pcl's own transformation interface `pcl::transformPointCloud` which takes Transforms as `Eigen` matrices.

However, `tf2_ros::Buffer::lookupTransform`, which seems to be the right interface to use, only returns `geometry_msgs::TransformStamped` and I can't find a one-liner to convert these (or, well, more likely the wrapped `geometry_msgs::Transform` to `Eigen::Matrix4f` or similar.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193757/how-to-convert-a-pointcloud-via-tf2/) by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2950 on 2014-09-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Vincent Rabaud recently opened a pull request to add support for exactly that. The pull-request is here. https://github.com/ros/geometry_experimental/pull/71  It will probably be merged and deployed after a review.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2014-09-30**:
Thanks, that answers one question.

What do we do about pcl::PointClouds? To use pcl::transformPointCloud we'd need a function to convert geometry_msgs::Transform to Eigen::Matrix4f. Could tf2::convert do that?

Otoh, pcl_ros is quite useful already, so how about extending its transforms.h?

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2014-09-30**:
Should the latter be done by adding pcl_ros::transformPointCloud functions for geometry_msgs::TransformStamped (which makes sense in the context of pcl_ros)
or by adding tf2::doTransform functions there (which makes sense in the context of tf2)?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-09-30**:
If you want to use the pcl transform function, just use [eigen_conversions](http://wiki.ros.org/eigen_conversions) to convert the transform into the needed eigen matrix.

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2014-10-01**:
Thanks, I didn't know about that package!